# Is it possible to create a Stack Exchange account without Facebook or Google accounts?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Is it at all possible to register for a Stack Exchange account with a non-Google email address?

Comment: Well the UX on the sign-up page isn’t exactly great. It’s not obvious just filling the form is an *alternative* to using Google/FB.

Comment: Since the `discussion` has just started... what about an `App Password`? Are `App Passwords` necessary on the `Super User` Web-Site?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai, not sure what you're asking, but sites can be accessed anonymously, without registering or logging in (what you can do without any rep is limited; rep is associated with an account).  Logging in requires a password to verify who you are, like anywhere else.

Comment: Hi @fixer1234, thanks for replying. We have registered using our _Google_ User Account. Will there be any need in the future to create an `App Password` also under these circumstances?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai, I didn't use Google to register, but I assume that when you created the site account, you specified a password.  Whatever that was is all you need.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Google and Facebook login uses OAuth or comparable mechanisms. Also, because no Google/Facebook services are accessed, it is entirely unrelated to app passwords and whatnot.

Comment: Great, guys, @fixer1234 and @Daniel B, thanks for your help. We have not specified any kind of passwords when we have used our _Google_ User Account in order to register on this Web-Site. Indeed, it is looking as if it is something like an _OAuth_ style of User Authentication. The funny thing is that _Vimeo_ has recently behaved in a similar way and yet they have required us to set an `App Password` also some time after the initial registration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is. Do not click the Sign up with Google or Sign up with Facebook buttons. Just fill in the fields.